# Manipulação de strings com Regex

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Tenho a seguinte string:

```js
const string = 'Isto é uma frase $[var_test["aaaa"].bbb], mais coisas $[var_test["ccc"].ddd].eee.fff mais coisas.'
```

Os elementos dinâmicos são:
var_test | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd | eee | fff | Isto é uma frase | , mais coisas | mais coisas.

Qual a melhor forma para devolver o seguinte output:

`Isto é uma frase $[var_test["aaaa"].bbb], mais coisas $[var_test["ccc"].ddd.eee.fff] mais coisas`

Eu pensei em fazer com regex, e fiz a seguinte regex, mas deve-me estar a faltar alguma coisa, pois faz match com: `$[var_test["aaaa"].bbb], mais coisas $[var_test["ccc"].`, e deveria-me fazer match com `$[var_test["ccc"].ddd].eee.fff`.

```js
var str = 'Isto é uma frase $[var_test["aaaa"].bbb], mais coisas $[var_test["ccc"].ddd].eee.fff mais coisas';
var patt = new RegExp(/\$\[.*?\[.*?].*?]\..*?\b/);
```

Alguém me pode dar umas dicas para solucionar/trabalhar/manipular strings da melhor forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma questão quando trabalhamos com expressão regular e dizemos a mesma que ela deve pegar qualquer caractere zero ou mais vezes `.*`, é que ela fará isso inclusive para caracteres especiais, e quando colocamos algum delineador ao final da expressão, esse delineador também esta contido nos termos de qualquer caractere, e portanto nossa expressão regular pegará tudo que está contido dentro do primeiro trecho possível até o último. Nesse caso `$[` e `].`.

Eu não conheço todas as possibilidades de combinação que sua string pode assumir, e em geral problemas com expressão regular podem ter mais de uma solução. Vou sugeri uma solução supondo que a *string* a qual você deseja realizar o *match* nunca poderá conter um espaço em branco.

Em uma expressão regular, para adicionar a regra de validação de não contido, utilize o acento circunflexo com sua expressão entre colchetes `[^ ]`. Você pode dessa forma procurar por qualquer caractere exceto o conjunto definido.

Se usarmos essa ideia de não contido, podemo alterar as referencias de `.*` em sua expressão por `[^ ]`, gerando o código abaixo:

```
var patt = new RegExp(/\$\[[^ ]*\[[^ ]*\][^ ]*\]\.[^ ]*/);
```

Também coloquei barra antes do fechamentos de colchetes que estavam faltando `\]`.

Caso deseje obter uma lista de todos os códigos iniciados com `$[` em sua string, indo desse início até o último caractere não em branco e não vírgula, use essa expressão:

```
var patt = new RegExp(/\$\[[^ ]*\]\.[^ ,]*/g);
```

Para saber mais sobre regras de expressão regular em JavaScript, acesse [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela informação que me ajudou a entender, como solução, utilizei a seguinte regex test.replace(/(\$\[\w*\[\"[\w-]*\"\]\.\w*)(\])(\.[\w\.]*)/g, "$1$3$2"); Agora acontece uma situação o ultimo caractere se for um . quero descartar o mesmo. Como poderia fazer essa negação? (Exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/85unb1hy/)

Comment: Entretanto já consegui solucionr o . com a seguinte regex: (\$\[\w*\[\"[\w-]*\"\]\.\w*)(\])(\.[\w\.]*[^ .])

Comment: Fica aqui o exemplo completo a funcionar: https://jsfiddle.net/85unb1hy/1/ Muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Gostaria de sugerir algumas melhorias na solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449895/112052) (e também da que você postou [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/449880/manipula%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-strings-com-regex#comment861924_449895)).

Em muitos lugares você usa o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`, que significa "**zero** ou mais caracteres". Isso quer dizer que se não tiver nenhum caractere, também será feita a substituição. Por exemplo, o trecho `$[[""].].x` será substituído por `$[[""]..x]`.

E a parte final da regex aceita coisas como `$[a["b"].].....fff` (que nesse caso é substituído por `$[a["b"]......fff]`). Isso porque foi usado `[\w\.]*` (zero ou mais caracteres que sejam `\w` ou ponto - ou seja, também aceita vários pontos seguidos).

É claro que se a string só tem entradas válidas e não há chances de ter esses falsos positivos, aí não tem problema usar a regex que foi sugerida. Mas se quiser ser mais preciso, pode fazer algumas alterações.

A primeira é trocar os `*` por `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências" (por exemplo, `\w*` viraria `\w+`). Isso faz com que pelo menos um caractere seja obrigatório. Se quiser ser ainda mais preciso, pode usar outros quantificadores, como por exemplo `\w{3,}` (no mínimo 3 ocorrências de `\w`), ou ainda `\w{3,10}` (no mínimo 3, no máximo 10). Ajuste os valores para o que fizer mais sentido para o seu caso.

E para o trecho final você pode usar `((?:\.\w+)+)`. A ideia é que a sequência `\.\w+` (um ponto seguido de uma ou mais letras, dígitos ou `_`) se repita uma ou mais vezes. Assim você evita casos como `....`. E assim eu nem preciso do `[^ .]` no final, pois essa regex já me garante que no final não pode ter ponto nem espaço. Eu também coloquei o trecho que se repete dentro de um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (delimitado por `(?:`), assim esses parênteses não criam outro grupo e não interfere na contagem usada na substituição (os números `$1`, `$2`, etc, que você usou [no seu exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/85unb1hy/1/)).

Enfim, ficaria assim:

```js
const str = 'Isto é uma frase $[var_test["aaaa"].bbb], esse não $[[""].x].y mais coisas $[var_test["ccc"].ddd].eee.fff mais coisas $[var_test["ccc"].ddd].eee.fff.';

const newStr = str.replace(/(\$\[\w+\[\"[\w-]+\"\]\.\w+)(\])((?:\.\w+)+)/g, "$1$3$2");
console.log(newStr);
```

---

Ainda dá para melhorar mais. No meio você usou `[\w-]` (um `\w` ou um hífen), ou seja, `\"[\w-]+\"` vai aceitar coisas como `"-----"`. Se a ideia é aceitar somente palavras com um hífen separando-as (como "abc-def", "abc-def-ghi", ou até mesmo sem hífen, como "abc", mas não aceitar "abc---def" e nem "-abc" ou "abc-" ou "---"), então mude este trecho para `\"\w+(?:-\w+)*\"` (entre as aspas temos um ou mais `\w`, seguido por zero ou mais ocorrências de "hífen seguido de `\w+`").

Enfim, regex é assim mesmo. Quanto mais precisa e específica ela é, mais complicada vai ficando. Cabe a você encontrar o equilíbrio entre a exatidão (chance de encontrar falsos positivos) *versus* a clareza e facilidade de manutenção. Como regra geral, é importante você [dizer claramente o que quer e o que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) que a regex pegue (por exemplo, "só quero um ponto seguido de algum caractere, e não quero dois ou mais pontos seguidos" - como eu fiz acima). Por outro lado, se as entradas são controladas e você sabe que não ocorrem casos como os já citados, então não precisaria mudar.